# запись и воспроизведение midi в NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

Пишу простенькое приложение(по нажатию на кнопку в миди файл должна записываться соответствующая нота, так же должна быть возможность проиграть этот миди файл.

```
 if (_isRecord)
            {
                var noteEvent = new NoteOnEvent(_coll.StartAbsoluteTime, 1, 65, 127, 100);
                _coll.AddEvent(noteEvent, 0);
            }
```

_coll - MidiEventCollection.
запись самого файла пытаюсь производить так

```
MidiFile.Export(@"../../myNewMidiFile" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".midi", _coll);
                _coll.Clear();
```

но файл оказывается очень коротким, полностью заполненным играющими от его начала до конца нотами, которые были нажаты

Comment: А как должно быть? Пауза - это тоже midi event.

Comment: Не видел его в документации. Не могли бы Вы подсказать как его создать?

Comment: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/MidiEvent.md#noteevent точно не подскажу, но кажется оно существует в документации, ну а как иначе?